# Textured viewport for UDIM material in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv, 3d-view

I understand that UDIM isn't really integrated yet (I'm on 2.74), but I'm wondering if anyone has found a solution to this issue:

I've got a character that's UV mapped onto 2 tiles (UDIM style I guess), one for face and one for body, and in Cycles I'm using a UDIM node group to correctly map the textures.

But I haven't been able to find a way to view the textures correctly in 'textured' mode in the viewport. His facial texture is just mapped to his body. Note teeth and gums on his right shoulder :O It's not a huge bummer, but it does make all my preview renders look ridiculous :)

I've tried assigning the diffuse textures in BI mode to the corresponding faces, but haven't got that to work yet.

Does anyone know if there is a solution/workaround to get texures displaying correctly in viewport (they work in rendered mode of course).

Thanks!
[image: UV layout]

[image: Nodes]

[image: Viewport textured mode]

Comment: Try Material view mode instead of Texture mode.  Texture mode doesn't take nodes into affect.

Comment: Max Puliero has a youtube tutorial with english subtitles that covers a good way to adapt to a UDIM style node system and keep track of the textures there. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NA9K5lMpEUo

Answer (score 1):

In edit mode you can assign different materials to different faces in an object. 
[image: screen shot]

If you have 2 materials:
Face
Body.

duplicate the material set up
set the input texture of the body and the Face correctly.

UV maps work on a value of 0-1 over the U and V axis, if you have a face outside of the grid, it restarts from 0, causing a repeat of the UV coordinates.